# Some algebraic manupilation of Fermat's last theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

## Meta

Some elementary manipulation of Fermat's theorem is tried and an approach to prove it in very few lines is suggested. The question is to pinpoint errors in the analysis, as usually these stuff is junk. Anyhow algebra is fun and I hope you'll enjoy the faulty ride. Can you see the mistake? I can't. I verified the last explicit formula for $n=3$ and $a=7$, $b=13$, $c = (a^3+b^3)^{1/3}$

### Here is the approach:

Consider the following equation over integers with $a \in \mathbb N, b \in \mathbb N, a < b, c \in
\mathbb N, n \geqslant 2, \text{odd}, \gcd(a,b)=1, \gcd(a,c)=1,\gcd(b,c)=1$,
$$ a^n + b^n = c^n. $$
Put $y = b / c$, $r = a / b$ and we get
$$ y^k = \frac{1}{1 + r^k} = \frac{1}{(1 + r) (1 - r + r^2 -r^3+ \cdots + r^{k -
   1})} = \frac{1}{(1 + r) u_{k - 1} (r)}. $$
Now we can rewrite this as
$$ y^k u_{k - 1} (r) = \frac 1{1+r} = \frac {1+r^k - r^k}{1+r} = u_{k - 1} (r) - r^k \frac{1}{1 +
   r} = u_{k - 1} (r) - r^k b / (b + a). $$
Multiply by $c^k b^{k - 1}(b+a)$ yields,
$$ (b + a) b^k b^{k - 1} u_{k - 1} (r) = (b + a) c^k b^{k - 1} u_{k - 1} (r) -
   c^k a^k. $$
Now note that,
$$ b^{k - 1} u_{k - 1} = b^{k - 1} - b^{k - 2} a^1 + \ldots \dotplus a^{k - 1}
   = b v (a, b) + a^{k - 1}, $$
And using this we conclude,
$$ (b + a) b^k (b v + a^{k - 1}) = (b + a) c^k b v + (b + a) c^k a^{k - 1} -
   c^k a^{k} = (b + a) c^k b v + c^k b a^{k - 1}. $$
Divide by $b$,
$$ (b + a) b^{k - 1} (b v + a^{k - 1}) = ((b + a) v + a^{k - 1}) c^k $$
Now, if $p \backslash (a + b)$ Then either $p \backslash c$ or $p \backslash
a$. If the latter then $p \backslash b$ which contradicts $\gcd (a, b) = 1$.

Hence we can write
$$ c = \alpha (a + b) $$
But $c < a + b$ hence a contradiction. This shows that Fermat's last theorem
holds for odd $n$ larger then 2. Then it holds also for every $n$ that has an odd prime as
a factor and the remaining cases follows from the special case $n = 4$ and Fermat's last theorem is proven.

Comment: Isn't $u_{k-1}(r) = (1-r+r^2 - \dots + r^{k-1})$? If so, doesn't the line after "Now we can rewrite this as" amount to asserting that $y^k = 1$?

Comment: In the first formula, $(1+r)(1-r+r^2+r^3+r^4) = 1+2r^3+2r^4+r^5 \neq 1+r^5$.

Comment: Why should $p$ have to divide $(a+b)$?

Comment: Hey I took time to answer your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4022480/riemann-hypothesis-example-derivation/4022551#4022551 please acknowledge that you understood something.

Comment: Sorry you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the crux of the problem, but in the final step the implication

$$(p \mid (a+b) \implies p\mid c)\implies c = \alpha(a+b)$$

is false in general if $\alpha$ is expected to be an integer.

For example, take $a+b = 27$ and $c=15$. (If you insist, take $a = 13, b=14$) then every prime that divides $a+b$ also divides $c$, but $c$ is not a multiple of $a+b$; moreover $a+b>c$ which does not lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Thx, yep that's the issue. However, for n==2 (a+b)^2 = a²+b²+2ab > c^2. Hence a+b > c = $\alpha$(a+b) > a + b contradiction. Similary for n > 2

Comment: @Stefan Why must $\alpha (a+b) > a+b$ when, as I have shown above, $\alpha$ may not be an integer?

Comment: your right that alpha is not proven to be an integer. But if it has to be ...

Comment: It does not "have to be". If we want it to be, we must put more effort into proving it; currently this proof is not sufficient.